# Signing executable with PKCS #7 SPC file using console version of signtool.exe

Tags: windows, ssl, key, certificate, signing

I am trying to sign an executable with PKCS #7 SPC file issued at Go Daddy. I have CSR (code signing request) file and PrivateKey.key file and .pem file with same name as .spc file. I am trying to use console version of signtool.exe:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin>signtool sign /t http://tsa.starfieldtech.com /csp "D:\SOMENAME.spc" /k "D:\SOMENAME.key" /sha1 HASH_MATCHING_RIGHT_CERT /v file_to_sign.exe
The following certificate was selected:
    Issued to: Monster, Inc.
    Issued by: Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority
    Expires:   Fri Dec 21 06:06:06 2014
    SHA1 hash: HASH_MATCHING_PARAMETER
SignTool Error: No private key is available.
```

I had previously installed spc file into My store. I got code signing certificate and two Go Daddy certificates.

What am I missing and what steps should I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to convert those two PKCS #7 keys to .pfx format using OpenSSL, and then use the more common way of signing using folowing command:

```
signtool sign /t http://tsa.starfieldtech.com /d "Description" /du "www.url.com" /f "cert.pfx" /p password /v file.exe
```